# How to recognize and crop a face in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm wondering which ways are available in order to select and crop a face of an imageView and then use it wherever we want.

I have no idea of this, so any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks guys.

Comment: Do you mean face recognition? Perhaps what you really want is to identify if there is a face in the ImageView and where? As it is, it's unclear (to me) what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the Core Image `CIDetector` class. (Type `CIDetectorTypeFace`.) It lets you detect faces in an image, and gives you a bounding rectangle for the faces it finds. the rectangle doesn't tend to enclose the person's entire head however, and the coordinate system it uses is different than that of a `UIImage`, so you'll have some work to do.

You should be able to find some tutorials online that detect faces and draw boxes around them. Erica Sadun's excellent iOS developer's cookbook series includes a sample app that draws boxes around faces, for example.